# Get isActiveNetworkMetered and isDefaultNetworkActive in API 29

Tags: java, android, android-10.0

After connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() got deprecated in API 29, it was quite a struggle to put together a network monitoring function that would also distinguish metered (cell) vs WiFi connection.

The problems I faced were 2:

1. connectivityManager.isActiveNetworkMetered() -- when both WiFi and Mobile data were on, it returned true (at least on my emulator, and I couldn't check on a device). When only WiFi was on, it returned false, as expected.
2. connectivityManager.isDefaultNetworkActive() -- it would always be active even if WiFi and Mobile were off.

The only way I found to work around this is via (1) onCapabilitiesChanged() and (2) getActiveNetwork()==null. The code is pasted below.

Do you know if there are other ways to do it? The whole implementation seems cumbersome, and the internet is full of deprecated examples.

Thanks

```
private static void monitorNetworks(){
        NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();

        connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(
                builder.build(),
                ncb = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                        scanAndSend();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLost(Network network) {
                        scanAndSend();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onUnavailable(){
                        scanAndSend();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCapabilitiesChanged (Network network,
                                                       NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities){
                        boolean metered = !networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_METERED);
                        Log.d(TAG, "NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_METERED: " +
                                String.valueOf(networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_METERED)));
                        sendMetered(metered);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    private static void scanAndSend(){
        boolean is_connected = false;
        if(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()==null) is_connected = false;
        else is_connected = true;
        sendConnectivityIntent(IS_NETWORK_AVAILABLE, is_connected);
    }

    private static void sendMetered(boolean metered) {
        sendIntent(IS_NETWORK_METERED, metered);
    }

    private static void sendIntent(String val_name, boolean val) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(val_name, val);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Note that "metered" is totally independent from the technology used (wifi vs cell). There are unlimited cell plans and metered wifi access points.

Comment: I see... But the problem is still there: if I have both a metered one and a non-metered one on, the isActiveNetworkMetered() would be true -- from what it seems